# variable set by VF page is not accessible in another method in Controller

Tags: visualforce, controller

I am setting a variable from VF page by using Javascript Remoting Action and the same variable when I am trying to access from a different method in Controller it always says NULL.

The below code explains the problem I am facing:

Variable is always null when trying to read from the method 'methodOne' in Controller but from the method setValue it shows the correct value sent from VF page.

Controller class:

```
global with sharing class MyController {
    public String variableOne{get;set;}

    public PageReference setValue() {
        System.debug('Variable value from setValue method is '+ variableOne); 
        //The above line prints the correct value "Andrew123"
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference methodOne() {
        System.debug('variable value from methodOne is '+ variableOne);
        //The above line always prints null Not sure Why
        return null;
    }
}
```

VisualForce Page:

```
    <apex:page extensions="MyController" >
        <script>
            function someMethod(){
                Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                        '{!$RemoteAction.MyController.remoteMethod}',                           
                        "Andrew",                           
                        function(result, event){
                            if (event.status) {   
                    setValueJS(result[0]['Id']);
                    methodOneJS();

                            }else{
                                console.log('event' + event.message);
                            } 
                        }
                    );          
            }

        </script type="text/javascript">

<apex:form>        
        <apex:actionFunction name="setValueJS" action="{!setValue}">
            <apex:param name="parm1" assignTo="" value=""/>
        </apex:actionFunction>
        <apex:actionFunction name="methodOneJS" action="{!methodOne}" />
</apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

Comment: Not sure how your page compiles. `MyController` is *not* a `standardController`, it is a *custom* `controller`. Also, I thought `actionFunction` had to be nested in a `form` tag. Finally, `methodOne` does not return any value. How did this ever save?

Comment: I just created this psuedo code to express my problem clearly..I edited the code now..Thanks for your time and sorry for misleading :)

Comment: @AdrianLarson It's possible we're just seeing a snippet of his code. Also, you edited out the `@RemoteAction` method. Aside from the compile issues, I think his code might work but it just behaves differently from how he describes it in his code comments.

Comment: Actually, it is not an extension either, it would be a controller (controller-MyController).  One issue is your setter (setValue) should be taking a parameter.

Comment: @JimRae Then how come debug statement in setValue method shows the value that I am passing from the page.. I thought <apex:param> for setValueJS is setting the controller variable.

Comment: @jmrjulian I edited out the `@RemoteAction` because it had nothing to do with his question.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I supposed that's exactly why his method was returning null -- because it doesn't actually do anything at all (contrary to his claim that he is ` setting a variable from VF page by using Javascript Remoting Action`).

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I understand you gave us a pseudocode that has errors and that doesn't compile, but I'll attempt to systematically pseudo-answer it anyway.

You cannot set `variableOne` from `MyController.remoteMethod` because

1. `variableOne` is an instance variable, and
2. `remoteMethod(String)` is a static method.

Static methods cannot access instance variables. Your code wouldn't have worked because it wouldn't have compiled in the first place.

As an alternative, create another instance method (ie, a method that does not have the `static` keyword) that sets the value of `variableOne`. For example

```
public void methodTwo() {
    variableOne = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('myParam');
}
```

You can bind this method to an `actionFunction` that passes a value through `myParam`.

With `methodTwo` in place, your current `methodOne` should return the correct value.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think My question was not clear..Actually I am fixing the existing code and not much of a salesforce guy..So i will comeback with a working class and page to express my problem clearly. I know about the static vs instance variable. Thanks for your time.